# does inetllij ide support spring+jsf out of the box

Tags: spring, jsf, intellij-idea

I'm searching "something" to help with developement of spring+jsf solutions.

I'm used to work with netbeans, but the integration between spring and jsf is to do by hand.

I've tried spring roo with the result of taking into many more technologies, starting with maven that i generally i don't use.

So I'm searching some other "all-in-one" package with spring + jsf well integrated out of the box, I really need to start developing my project.

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, IntelliJ IDEA supports Spring, JSF plus [many more](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/features/?fromIndex) out of the box. Be aware that many of those are only available in the ultimate edition.

Comment: just downloaded last release of intellij idea (10.something) community edition, it seem not to support any framework out of the box! just "maven" and "groovy"... are they frameworks??

Comment: @agostinox, if you look in my anser, you will see exactly where in the preferences the support for jsf is.  You might have to get the ultimate addition.

Answer (score 2):

there is a jsf plugin, but I am unsure if it is available in the free version or if you need to upgrade.  Also, I cannot vouch as to the quality as I don't use jsf.  You can try the paid version for free for 30 days, so if it is not in the free version you can at least check out its utility.

[image]